# Idea IntelliJ 14.1 Out of memory

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

[image: Out of Memory]

Has someone experienced this?, what value would you suggest for Xmx?

Extra info: It is running in 32 bit (idea.exe)

Comment: are you running on a 32-bit OS? Try the 64-bit version if not

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit, yes, now seems working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to make it run with the following configuration in idea64.exe.vmoptions:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx1512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=500m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

I switched over 64 bit (idea64.exe), the IDE starts, and seems that it has enough memory to load 4 projects with their web applications each.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the work that you do with IntelliJ (if you work much with larger files, then you should increase the memory more than if you only work with smaller files or projects). I have set Xmx to 2048 MB.

Comment: I have increased to 2048 but Intellij does not start even

Comment: Ah, i just saw you use the 32bit version. Then you have to try a smaller amount (like 1536).